# Python: How can I define a class in a doctest?

Tags: python, unit-testing, class, doctest

I would like to use a doctest comment block to demonstrate the usage of a particular base class, but either this cannot be done with doctest or I am doing something wrong.
Here is my simple demo code.

```
class MyClass(object):
    '''
    >>> m = MyClass()
    >>> print m.x
    1
    >>> class A(MyClass):
    >>>  def __init__(self):
    >>>    super(A,self).__init__()
    >>>
    >>> a = A()
    >>> print a.x
    1
    '''


    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 1


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import doctest
    doctest.testmod()
```

The code doesn't run. Here's the first error issued:

```
Failed example:
class A(MyClass):
Exception raised:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\doctest.py", line 1254, in __run
    compileflags, 1) in test.globs
  File "<doctest __main__.MyClass[2]>", line 1
    class A(MyClass):
                    ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
```

Comment: @avasal: My mistake; the wohle post was incorrectly formatted and I reindented that section with the rest of the class.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try it out in the interpreter; it uses `...` to show continuation lines. `>>>` is only for a *new* statement or expression, while a `class` in incomplete until you've had an empty `...` continuation line:

```
    >>> class A(MyClass):
    ...     def __init__(self):
    ...         super(A, self).__init__()
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, works like a charm now! Another side problem that I ran into was that newlines as in "some string\n" cause trouble. I replaced them with +os.sep . Just in case somebody else with the same question reads this.

Comment: @Sven: `os.sep`? Why not *double* the ``\`` to `\\n` instead? `os.sep` is `/` on UNIX platforms, for example.